# PDF file returns as unsupported format which is created and downloaded using Java( Java EE)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf-generation, itext

when I am executing this jsp file, I am able to download the file in pdf format.but when i ma trying to open it is displaying an error that unsupported format. But if i try to open the downloaded the pdf file in notepad I am getting the my desired data.But I should get it in a decrypted form.so please help me out to open the pdf file for viewing data..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%  String ID = (String) session.getAttribute("ID");
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    String url = request.getParameter("WEB_URL");
    String Content = new String("");
    Statement stmt = null;
    Connection con = null;


String Content = new String("");
                String filename = "data" + ID + ".pdf";

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "temp",

            "root");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String qry = "select * from form where id='" + ID + "'";
            ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
            if (rst.next()) {
                Content = "  FirstName: " + rst.getString("FirstName")
                        + "\r\n" + "  LastName: "
                        + rst.getString("LastName") + "\r\n" + "  Age: "
                        + rst.getString("Age") + "\r\n" + "  City: "
                        + rst.getString("City") + "\r\n" + "  Phone: "
                        + rst.getString("Phone") + "\r\n" + "  ID: "
                        + rst.getString("ID");
            }
            //out.println(Content);
            byte requestBytes[] = Content.getBytes();
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

            ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    requestBytes);
            BufferedInputStream bufStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                    byteStream);
            ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = response
                    .getOutputStream();
            int data = bufStream.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                responseOutputStream.write(data);
                data = bufStream.read();
            }

            bufStream.close();
            responseOutputStream.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" Exception is:" + e);
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly what is wrong, you are outputting HTML too around the PDF output. Make sure that you start with `<%` and end with `%>` without final newline; that is good style, even if  `response.reset()` might function here.

Furthermore `content.getBytes("Cp1252")` (Windows Latin-1, extension of your ISO-8859-1). Otherwise the platform encoding is default.

And it seems you output the string `Content` not the pdf (filename).

```
File file = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/pdfsdir/" + filename);
FileInputStream byteStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

As PDF is binary the setCharacterEncoding is not needed.
For a file you might however set the Content-Length header.

For filling in the personalized data one would need more.

---

Early on do:

```
        File file = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/pdfsdir/" + filename);
        if (!file.canRead()) {
            // Log this with filename...
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }
        long fileLength = file.length();
        if (fileLength > Integer.MAX_VALUE) { // Too large
            // Log this with filename...
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT);
            return;
        }
        int length = (int) fileLength;
```

After:

```
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + filename);
```

do

```
        response.setContentLength(length);

        FileInputStream byteStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bufStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                byteStream);
        ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = response
                .getOutputStream();
        final int BLOCK_SIZE = Math.min(16*1024, length);
        byte[] data = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        while (length > 0) {
            int nread = bufStream.read(data, 0, Math.max(length, block.length));
            if (nread <= 0) {
                // Something fishy happened, upload of other smaller version.
                break;
            }
            length -= nread;
            responseOutputStream.write(data, 0, nread);
        }
        bufStream.close();
```

Comment: +1 Also: one must make sure not to introduce any white space between the tags. PDF is a binary format where byte positions are important. If you have extra white space in your JSP script, you corrupt all the byte pointers.

Comment: If the pdf would be in a top web directory `pdfsdir` the code above would substitute the old `byteStream` creation. Then it should work. I will add a bit faster download, not byte by byte.

Comment: Thanks for answering .but I am getting same problem..i.e unable to open pdf.If I change filename as .doc extension I am getting the doc file and able to view the required content..let this is my entire code

Comment: Aha! Maybe you want to generate a PDF file with the info from the database? **That** is not written in 20 lines. Search for (for instance) itext examples; itext is one java PDF library.